# doc2vec/gensim - issue with shuffling sentences in the epochs

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

I am trying to get started with `word2vec` and `doc2vec` using the excellent tutorials, [here](http://linanqiu.github.io/2015/10/07/word2vec-sentiment/) and [here](https://medium.com/@mishra.thedeepak/doc2vec-in-a-simple-way-fa80bfe81104) and trying to use the code samples. I only added in a `line_clean()` method to remove punctuation, stopwords etc.

But I am having trouble with the `line_clean()` method called in the training iterations.  I understand the call to the global method is messing it up, but I am not sure how to get past this problem.

```
Iteration 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/santino/Dev/doc2vec_exp/doc2vec_exp_app/doc2vec/untitled.py", line 96, in <module>
    train()
  File "/Users/santino/Dev/doc2vec_exp/doc2vec_exp_app/doc2vec/untitled.py", line 91, in train
    model.train(sentences.sentences_perm(),total_examples=model.corpus_count,epochs=model.iter)
  File "/Users/santino/Dev/doc2vec_exp/doc2vec_exp_app/doc2vec/untitled.py", line 61, in sentences_perm
    shuffled = list(self.sentences)
AttributeError: 'TaggedLineSentence' object has no attribute 'sentences'
```

My code is below:

```
import gensim
from gensim import utils
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
import os
import random
import numpy
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import logging
import sys
from nltk import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
stopword_set = set(stopwords.words('english'))


def clean_line(line):
    new_str = unicode(line, errors='replace').lower() #encoding issues
    dlist = tokenizer.tokenize(new_str)
    dlist = list(set(dlist).difference(stopword_set))
    new_line = ' '.join(dlist)
    return new_line


class TaggedLineSentence(object):
    def __init__(self, sources):
        self.sources = sources

        flipped = {}

        # make sure that keys are unique
        for key, value in sources.items():
            if value not in flipped:
                flipped[value] = [key]
            else:
                raise Exception('Non-unique prefix encountered')

    def __iter__(self):
        for source, prefix in self.sources.items():
            with utils.smart_open(source) as fin:
                for item_no, line in enumerate(fin):
                    yield TaggedDocument(utils.to_unicode(clean_line(line)).split(), [prefix + '_%s' % item_no])

    def to_array(self):
        self.sentences = []
        for source, prefix in self.sources.items():
            with utils.smart_open(source) as fin:
                for item_no, line in enumerate(fin):
                    self.sentences.append(TaggedDocument(utils.to_unicode(clean_line(line)).split(), [prefix + '_%s' % item_no]))
        return(self.sentences)

    def sentences_perm(self):
        shuffled = list(self.sentences)
        random.shuffle(shuffled)
        return(shuffled)


def train():
    #create a list data that stores the content of all text files in order of their names in docLabels
    doc_files = [f for f in os.listdir('./data/') if f.endswith('.csv')]

    sources = {}
    for doc in doc_files:
        doc2 = os.path.join('./data',doc)
        sources[doc2] = doc.replace('.csv','')

    sentences = TaggedLineSentence(sources)


    # #iterator returned over all documents
    model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(size=300, min_count=2, alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.025)
    model.build_vocab(sentences)

    #training of model
    for epoch in range(10):
        #random.shuffle(sentences)
        print 'iteration '+str(epoch+1)
        #model.train(it)
        model.alpha -= 0.002
        model.min_alpha = model.alpha
        model.train(sentences.sentences_perm(),total_examples=model.corpus_count,epochs=model.iter)
    #saving the created model
    model.save('reddit.doc2vec')
    print "model saved" 

train()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those aren't great tutorials for the latest versions of `gensim`. In particular, it's a bad idea to be calling `train()` multiple times in a loop with your own manual management of `alpha`/`min_alpha`. It's easy to mess up – the wrong things will happen in your code, for example – and offers no benefit for most users. Don't change `min_alpha` from the default, and call `train()` exactly once – it'll then do exactly `epochs` iterations, decaying the learning-rate `alpha` from its max to min values properly.

Your specific error is because your `TaggedLineSentence` class doesn't have a `sentences` property – at least not until after `to_array()` is called – and yet the code is trying to access that non-existent property.

The whole `to_array()`/`sentences_perm()` approach is a bit broken. The reason for using such an iterable class is typically to keep a large dataset out of main-memory, streaming it from disk. But `to_array()` then just loads everything, caching it *inside* the class - eliminating the iterable benefit. If you can afford that, because the full dataset easily fits in memory, you can just do...

```
sentences = list(TaggedLineSentence(sources)
```

...to iterate-from-disk once, then keep the corpus in an in-memory list.

And shuffling repeatedly during training isn't usually needed. Only if the training data has some existing clumping – like all the examples with certain words/topics are stuck together at the top or bottom of the ordering – is the native ordering likely to cause training problems. And in that case, a single shuffle, before any training, should be enough to remove the clumping. So again assuming your data fits in memory, you can just do...

```
sentences = random.shuffle(list(TaggedLineSentence(sources)
```

...once, then you've got a `sentences` that's fine to pass to `Doc2Vec` in both `build_vocab()` and `train()` (once) below.